# Get single Array value from ParseObject

Tags: android, arrays, parsing, parse-platform

Simple question, I've got a ParseObject, retreived from Parse.com with a column that contains an array with Integer values.

How can I get single values from that Array in Android.

I didn't find anything nor in the documention neither in web.

I Would appreciate it if someone could help :)

[image: Here's the object]
[image: My Parse db]

Comment: so you have an array object with integer values. It should be the same as with simple array object in Java, something like `arrayObject[1]`, `arrayObject[idOfWhatYouWant]`

Comment: post some code or something that will help us to solve your problem

Comment: the problem is a ParseObject is no ArrayObject. Here are the methods of the ParseObject: https://www.parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseObject.html but i have no idea which one i got to use and how. I add some pictures in my question.

Comment: look like [getJSONArray()](https://www.parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseObject.html#getJSONArray(java.lang.String)) or [getList()](https://www.parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseObject.html#getList(java.lang.String)) would be the way to go. Have you tried those?

Comment: Come out with a code where you stucked exactly. I use parse and can retrieve data without any problems, and their docs was enough for me.

Comment: Alright, got my answer, with getJSONArray() it works :) thank you :)